# How should celery pick tasks from database

Tags: python, django, celery

I have python django web application.
When user submits the request then i have to insert 10 rows in database , basically which are tasks that has to completed.

I can have function which gets those tasks and then celery can run those functions.

```
@shared_task
def provision(tasks):
    for tasks in tasks:
       pass
```

My problem is

1. Some tasks i want o happen in sequqnce after other
2. some tasks i want to happen in parallel
3. IN case some tasks failed then i should be able to restart them

I am not sure how will celery help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The Celery framework provides some [workflow primitives](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) that allows you run tasks in sequence ([chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains)) or in parallel ([group](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups)).

Celery also comes with a built-in [retry mechanism](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying).